# Create custom shortcut for turning on line numbers (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I need to know if there is a way to create a custom shortcut for turning on line numbers in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was almost there - in the same window there is a button Keyboard - from there you can assign shortcuts to the macros.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in macro for this.

- Right click a toolbar and select "Customize"
- Select the "Commands" tab
- Decide where you want to add this (Menu bar, Toolbar,  context menu)
- Click "Add Command..."
- Under the "Macros" category there are:

  - "Macros.Samples.Utilties.TurnOffLineNumbers"
  - "Macros.Samples.Utilties.TurnOnLineNumbers"

Done.